# Tcp server client Connection issue in C

Tags: c, sockets

so i am trying to implement a TCP server-client(s) using server ip and port. Connection between the two was established, with the use of threads.

Now i'm expecting the program to: for everytime a client joins or leave, if there are other clients present, then it will print "Client  has joined/left the server" on these other clients screen. However if it is the only client present, it won't say the join or leave stuff and will proceed with asking user an input of what does the client wants to do.(user input is what the client has typed after this arrow ">")

What it is actually doing: When the first client has successfully joined the server, the command line remains empty, the ">" does not appear and even if you can type, no input is recorded by the client. As you connect a second client, that's when the arrow appears on the first client only and you can start inputting.

I would like to know which part i should edit to make my client when alone to start taking input without needing another client to join before doing so + When there are multiple clients and a client joins/leave, on the other clients' screen is printed "Client  has joined/left the server"

Server code

```
void client_queuing(client_thr *cl){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cli_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i < MAXLINE; ++i){
        if(!cli[i]){
            cli[i] = cl;
            break;
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli_mutex);
}

void client_removal(int uid){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cli_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i < MAXLINE; ++i){
        if(cli[i]){
            if(cli[i]->uid == uid){
                cli[i] = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli_mutex);
}

void convey_msg(char *st, int uid){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cli_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i<MAXLINE; ++i){
        if(cli[i]){
            if(cli[i]->uid != uid){
                if(write(cli[i]->sockfd, st, strlen(st)) < 0){
                    perror("ERROR: Failure to write to descriptor");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cli_mutex);
}

void *man_cli(void *arg){
    char buffer_o[SIZEOF_BUFFER];
    char nickname[20];
    int leave_flag = 0;

    num_client++;
    client_thr *clice = (client_thr *)arg;

    // nickname
    if(recv(clice->sockfd, nickname, 20, 0) <= 0 || strlen(nickname) >= 19){
        printf("Name not Entered.\n");
        leave_flag = 1;
    } 
    else{
        strcpy(cli->nickname, nickname);
        sprintf(buffer_o, "A new user %s has joined SNC!\n", cli->nickname);
        printf("%s", buffer_o);
        convey_msg(buffer_o, clice->uid);
    }

    bzero(buffer_o, SIZEOF_BUFFER);

    while(1){
        if (leave_flag) {
            break;
        }

        int receive = recv(clice->sockfd, buffer_o, SIZEOF_BUFFER, 0);
        if (receive > 0){
            if(strlen(buffer_o) > 0){
                convey_msg(buffer_o, clice->uid);

                array_trimming(buffer_o, strlen(buffer_o));
                printf("%s -> %s\n", buffer_o, clice->nickname);
                //printf("%s\n", buffer_o);
            }
        } 
        else if (receive == 0 || strcmp(buffer_o, "quit") == 0){
            sprintf(buffer_o, "Server: %s has stopped chatting.\n", clice->nickname);
            printf("%s", buffer_o);
            convey_msg(buffer_o, clice->uid);
            //trial
            //strcpy(buffer_o, clice->nickname);
            send(clice->sockfd, buffer_o, strlen(buffer_o)+1,0);
            leave_flag = 1;
        } 
/*      else {
            printf("Error is -1\n");
            leave_flag = 1;
        } */

        bzero(buffer_o, SIZEOF_BUFFER);
    }

  /* Delete client from queue and yield thread */
    close(clice->sockfd);
    client_removal(clice->uid);
    free(clice);
    num_client--;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    return NULL;
}
```

client code

```
void handle_message_convey() {
    char message[LENGTH] = {};
    char buff[LENGTH + 20] = {};
    while(1) {
        flush_stdout();
        fgets(message, LENGTH, stdin);
        array_trimming(message, LENGTH);

        if (strcmp(message, "quit") == 0) {
            break;
        } 
        else {
            sprintf(buff, "%s: %s\n", nickname, message);
            send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buff), 0);
        }

        bzero(message, LENGTH);
        bzero(buffer, LENGTH + 20);
    }
    quit_with_catch_ctrl_c(2);
}

void handle_message_recv() {
    char message[LENGTH] = {};
    while (1) {
        int message_rcv = recv(sockfd, message, LEN, 0);
        if (message_rcv > 0) {
            printf("%s", message);
            flush_stdout();
        } 
        else if (message_rcv == 0) {
            break;
        } 
        else {
            // nothing happens = -1
        }
        memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
    }
}
int main(){
recv(sock_fd, buffer_o, sizeof(buffer_o), 0);
    //printf("%s \n", buffer_o);
    
    pthread_t message_sending_thr;
    if(pthread_create(&message_sending_thr, NULL, (void* ) handle_message_convey, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("Error with pthread:");
    }
    
    //printf("Hello, Welcome!");
    pthread_t message_del_thr;
    if(pthread_create(&message_del_thr, NULL, (void *)handle_message_recv, NULL) != 0){
        printf("Error with pthread");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect here. There is no code, no expectation was the (missing) code should do and no description what it does instead and where you need help. Please follow the recommendations in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you expect good help. Apart from that, please don't post screenshots of text (code, output ...) , but include the text directly properly formatted into your question.

Comment: okay i'll reask my question